# Static IP Address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, static-ip-address, elastic-ip

I have a client who has his API's hosted on Azure Devops. In order to allow me to access their API's they want a static IP from me so that they could whitelist my IP to allow me access.

My question is how do I create a static IP and if they are 2 other developers working on the same project, how can we all access the API's without being blocked.

What I tried:
Created an Elastic IP on EC2. And I need some guidance on how I could associate that static ip to  3 different computers on different networks. Or if you could throw some light on what is my best approach here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From which locations do you need to access the API? (You mention EC2 elastic IP but it is unclear what AWS has to do with the whole setup?)

Answer (score 0):

The remote API provider will need to whitelist all of your developers IP addresses. That shouldn't be a problem. You would assign an elastic IP to each instance / developer and then they can gain access to the remote API. There is no reason you have to share an elastic IP. It is quite common to have multiple entries in a given whitelist. Have them add all three.